Laplace transform of $f(t) = g(t) \cos(at)$
I would like to know if there is a compact way to express the laplace transform of the function $f(t) = g(t) \cos(at)$ using the Laplace transform G of the function g. Using the Euler's formula for the cosine, I end up with
$$\mathcal{L}\{ g(t) \cos(at) \}(s) = \frac{1}{2} \left( G(s - ia) + G(s + ia) \right). $$
Can I express this last formula in a more compact way, obtaining something that resembles the laplace transform of the cosine
$$\frac{s}{s^2 + a^2}?$$

What you have already is excellent. Further simplications would only depend on $G.$

Okay, thank you!
